# php get all files from a remote directory

Tags: php, image

I have searched, and searched for 3+ hours this morning and tried over 10 different setups for how to grab and display a list of images from a url, and none of them worked correctly. I would either end up with no info displaying, or a 500 error. Can someone point me to an example or help me out here on how to do this properly. file_get_contents is not a viable option.

Example Directory: http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/

Files i know that are in that directory:
001.jpg,
002.jpg,
003.jpg

I would like the output to be the exact url to the file.

Let me know if more info is needed, i'm not 100% sure exactly how to explain it right lol.

Edit:

ok so what I guess i actually want to do is check the url for all the image tags and display a list with the full url to that image.

New to working with this url+images+php stuff so please don't hit me too hard with your downvote hammer with no comments lol.

Code I Tried:

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/

$url = $location;

// Fetch page
$string = FetchPage($url);

// Regex that extracts the images (full tag)
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$img_tag_array = $out[0];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($img_tag_array); echo "</pre>";

// Regex for SRC Value
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$images_url_array = $out[1];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($images_url_array); echo "</pre>";

// Fetch Page Function

function FetchPage($path)
{
$file = fopen($path, "r"); 

if (!$file)
{
exit("The was a connection error!");
} 

$data = '';

while (!feof($file))
{
// Extract the data from the file / url

$data .= fgets($file, 1024);
}
return $data;
}
?>
```

and it returned a blank page

Comment: Downvote with no comment... thanks!

Comment: After reading your question 8-10 more times I've now thoroughly confused myself and am not sure if my answer helps at all. Why isn't file_get_contents() an option? That url is not a directory.. it's a website. What do you mean when you say "File i know that are in that directory"? Do you just want to get all images used on a page? Which images? Just the `<img>` tags or the ones used in css as well?

Comment: i'm sorry i told you i dont know how to explain it correctly lol. What i want to do is grab all the <img> tags and display them as a list to me as a full url to that image. And i read in another post that file_get_contents doesn't always get all the files... I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: I think what OP is trying to do is parse the HTML contents of `http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/` to extract all `<img/>` `src` attributes. You really do need to use `file_get_contents()` or the equivalent, in order to get the data into PHP in the first place.

Comment: yeah exactly, my brain knows what it wants i just can't always explain it right lol.

Comment: does your hosting environment prohibit `file_get_contents()`? Is that the reason you wish to not use it?

Comment: its not my hosting environment... I want to get a list of the images used in that url.

Comment: Got ya. Give me a few minutes, I will work something up for you :)

Comment: thank you for actually taking the time to 1) straighten my question out & 2) actually helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based loosely on the code you already tried (but was riddled with problems). This grabs the full contents of the URL `$url`, parses out the `<img>` `src` attributes, and then outputs them.

Because this particular web host uses `<base href=""/>` tag to reset the base part of all URLs on the page, I've added a `$base` variable which you should set to the contents of the base tag.

Additionally, it looks like this particular web host has some pretty smart anti-hotlinking in place, so not all images may be visible.

But! Give it a whirl, let me know if it does what you need it to, and any questions.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/';
$base = 'http://www.webtoonlive.com/';

// Pull in the external HTML contents
$contents = file_get_contents( $url );

// Use Regular Expressions to match all <img src="???" />
preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]*src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui', $contents, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach ( $out[1] as $k=>$v ){ // Step through all SRC's

    // Prepend the URL with the $base URL (if needed)
    if ( strpos( $v, 'http://' ) !== true ) $v = $base . $v;

    // Output a link to the URL
    echo '<a href="' . $v . '">' . $v . '</a><br/>';
}
```

Sample output:

```
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/000.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/001.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/002.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/003.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/004.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/005.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/006.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/007.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/008.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/009.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/010.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/011.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/012.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/013.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/014.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/015.jpg
http://www.webtoonlive.com/webtoon/fantasy_world_survival/ch02/016.jpg
```

Comment: Works flawlessy when $url does not = another variable. but when i switch it to `$url = $location` it displays a blank page with nothing on it. `$location = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['q']);` is what it is set as.

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump( $_REQUEST['q'] );` ? Looking to see what the contents are of your `$_REQUEST['q']` variable. Unless you're putting the URL back into a database, you can probably do without the `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: wierd changed it back to `$url = $location` and it worked the second time around... maybe i mispelled something first run lol... Thank you for your time works great. Now i can fetch comics way faster than having to search for the link 1 by 1 in the view source output lol.